# How to solve "System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object" in apex class

Tags: apex, visualforce, controller

I have written the following code. It's working fine in sandbox and deployed it to production after moving it to production I am getting the following error:

> System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object Class.EmployeeController.: line 8, column 1

What might be the reason for this error?

Here's my code:

```
public with sharing class EmployeeController {

    public Call_Data_Flow__c emp{get;set;}
    Public String Returnurl{get; set;}       
    public EmployeeController(ApexPages.StandardController Controller){   
        Returnurl = Apexpages.currentpage().getparameters().get('retURL');
        emp = new Call_Data_Flow__c(); 
        emp.Lead__c = Returnurl.subString(1);     
    } 

    public PageReference save() {  
        insert emp; 
        return new PageReference ('/'+Returnurl );
    }

    public PageReference cancel() {  
        return new PageReference ('/'+Returnurl );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A few different reasons can lead to `Returnurl` being null:

- The `retURL` parameter is not included in your url
- The `retURL` parameter is differently cased (page parameters are case sensitive)

Regardless of the fact this variable might be null, your current code assumes it is not when you call `ReturnUrl.subString(1)`. At that point the code tries to de-reference the null `ReturnUrl` variable and explodes. Add a null check:

```
if (ReturnUrl != null) emp.Lead__c = ReturnUrl.subString(1);
```